# Ruby: Create function to find the word with most repeated letters

Tags: ruby

So I'm getting the error

```
#test.rb:5:in `block in <main>': undefined method `length' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)                                                                                    
#from test.rb:4:in `each'                                                                                                                                              
#from test.rb:4:in `<main>'
```

Any help is much appreciated

```
str = "one two three"
str = str.split(" ")
counter = 0
most_repeat_letter_word = nil

str.each do |char|
if char.length - char.split("").uniq!.length > counter 
most_repeat_letter_word = char
end
end
puts most_repeat_letter_word
```

Comment: reads a bit too much like homework for me

Comment: just practice for applying to a programming bootcamp :)

Comment: I still think it's expected of you to ask well-formed questions per the FAQ and Meta expectations.  Welcome to the site, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two problems:

- `counter` is not being updated.
- [Array#uniq](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-uniq-21) returns `nil` if no change is made (as do many "bang" methods), raising the exception. Use `uniq`.

This should work:

```
str = "one two three"
arr = str.split
counter = 0
most_repeat_letter_word = nil

arr.each do |w|
  candidate = w.length - w.split('').uniq.length
  if candidate  > counter 
    most_repeat_letter_word = w
    counter = candidate
  end
end
puts most_repeat_letter_word
  #=> three
```

**Edit:** Alas, I misread the question (even though I corrected the OP's stab), but I did answer another interesting question.  `squeeze` needs to be replace by `uniq`  above, as @DarkMouse did in his answer.**]**

You can use [String#squeeze](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/String.html#method-i-squeeze) to advantage here, to remove duplicate repeated characters:

```
str = "Three blind mice, see how they run."
str.split.max_by { |w| w.size-w.downcase.squeeze.size }
  #=> "Three"
```

Comment: isn't str = str.split(" ") splitting the string into an array? Then when I call the uniq! method I turn that char being called into an array with split("")

Comment: I beg your pardon. You are correct. I confess I need to look at your code more closely, and will add anything I think is useful to my answer, if others have not already diagnosed your problem.

Comment: @ChrisWilson You get the `NoMethodError` because `uniq!` will return `nil` if the array is already unique. You're probably looking for the normal `uniq` method.

Comment: Haha yeah I was just about to say that I figured it out.  Thanks!

Comment: #squeeze is only going to remove concurrent repeated letters, which won't quite satisfy the conditions here.

Comment: @Chris, oh, drat, I so much wanted to `squeeze` that I mind brain changed the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can find this by using Enumerable's max_by function.

```
str = ["one", "two", "three"]
str.max_by{|s|s.chars.count - s.chars.uniq.count}
=> "three"
```